# Show Ionic Popup after exceeding maximum number of digits in a textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, popup, calculator

I'm currently working on a basic calculator using Ionic1 and AngularJS. I want to limit the number of digits inputted on the screen to only 15digits. I want to show an ionic popup to the user. 
I am using numeric key(buttons) for inputting numbers in my calculator. How can I do that?

Comment: can you not do a maxlength="15" so it never exceeds 15?

Comment: I can set it but i also want to display a popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change and sending ng-model value in controller,in controller check length of input once its equal to 15 you can show pop up

Answer (score 0):

You can watch your model value using `$scope.$watch`.

**view.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue">
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.$watch('inputValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue.length === 15) {
        showPopup(); // your function to show popup
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="input" id="myinput1" value="0" size="15" maxlength="15" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=myinput1]').keypress(validateNumber);
});
$( "#myinput1" ).on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length>=15) {
        alert('show pop up');       
    }
});
function validateNumber(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
        return true;
    } else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2j664qrw/1/)